# Camel delay overrides any redeliveryPolicy

Tags: java, apache-camel

Here is a simplified ftp polling mechanism.

```
<camelContext id="Fetcher" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">

    <redeliveryPolicyProfile id="redeliveryPolicy"
        redeliveryDelay="10000" 
        maximumRedeliveries="-1" />

    <camel:route id="fetchFiles">  
        <camel:from uri="ftp://10.20.30.40/From?username=user&password=RAW({{password}})&delay=3000" />
        <camel:to uri="log:input?showAll=true&level=INFO"/>
        <camel:to uri="file://incomingDirectory" />

        <onException redeliveryPolicyRef="msRedeliveryPolicy">
            <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
            <redeliveryPolicy logRetryAttempted="true" retryAttemptedLogLevel="WARN"/>
        </onException>      
    </camel:route>

</camelContext>
```

> What do you think happens on failure?   (Delay is 3 seconds, and
>   redeliveryDelay is 10 seconds.)
>
> Answer:  It polls every 3 seconds, forever.

So let's look at the docs.  Maybe I need this

```
"repeatCount (scheduler)"

Specifies a maximum limit of number of fires. So if you set it to 1, the scheduler will only fire once. If you set it to 5, it will only fire five times. A value of zero or negative means fire forever.

Default: 0
```

Nope, it's not even a valid parameter.  So why's it in the docs?

```
 Unknown parameters=[{repeatCount=5}]
```

Ok, so I suppose every 3 seconds it polls.  So how do I tell camel to stop that?  Let's try set 'handled' to true?

```
<onException redeliveryPolicyRef="msRedeliveryPolicy">
    <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
    <redeliveryPolicy logRetryAttempted="true" retryAttemptedLogLevel="WARN"/>
    <handled><constant>true</constant></handled>
</onException>
```

No luck.  Still 3 seconds.  It's clearly not even getting to the redelivery part.

What's the secret?

Comment: Hi @djb! I'm slightly confused as to what you are trying to achieve? Is it the polling that is generating the error, or the rest of the processing? I think the re-delivery policy is only relating to exchanges, but if your consumer is failing then you're not even getting an exchange. You might want to look at `backoffErrorThreshold` and `backoffMultplier`  which might give you what you want if it is the consumer you want to manage.

Comment: Hey, so I ended up using the backoffMultiplier and threshold, in the end, and getting rid of the exception handling.  

I think the issue is that redeliveryPolicy probably just doesn't effect the polling delay.  I thought that since it throws an exception, it would retry after 10 seconds, but nope.

Answer (score 1):

The fact is errors happen in from endpoint are not handled by user defined route (i.e. `fetchFiles` in above setup). So, `onException` and `redeliveryPolicy` are not involved as they only affect stuff belongs to user defined route.

To control the behavior of consumer defined in from endpoint, the obvious way is to use the option exist in that component. As suggested by @Screwtape, use `backoffErrorThreshold` and `backoffMultplier` for your case.

Why parameter `repeatCount` exist in doc, but is invalid to use? It probably does not exist in your camel version and Camel document writer forget to mark the first exist version in the doc.

Comment: thanks, so the thing I'm not entirely sure about is, what's the difference between an error from an endpoint, and an error from a route?  (the endpoint is part of the route)

Comment: My guess is Camel try to separate the responsibility of error handling. If Camel allow user defined route to intercept the camel component, then there will be way too much scenario to handle.